# I want to proof that $∑_{c∈F_{q}}f(c)^{q-1}=-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, finite-fields

[ Let $f\in \mathbb{F}_q[x]$, with $f$ has only one root over $\mathbb{F}_q$. I want to proof that $∑_{c∈F_{q}}f(c)^{q-1}=-1$][1]

[1]:

Comment: You *prove* something, and to do so, you provide a *proof*.

Comment: $f$ is not necessarily one-to-one

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

without loss of generality let the single root of the polynomial be $c = 0$.  (Otherwise shift the polynomial via $g(x) = f(x+r)$).

For $c \not= 0$, $f(c) \not= 0$, since this was your only root.  Forget about the polynomial $f$ and just write $f(c) = g_c$, knowing that $g_c \in F^{\times}_q$.
Your sum becomes 
$$
\sum_{c\in F^{\times}_q} g_c^{q-1}
$$
Now you should know a couple of things about $F^{\times}_q$.  It's an Abelian group of order $q-1$.  What can you say about the orders of the elements in such a group?

Comment: the order is $q-1$ or divisor of $q-1$

Comment: right, you've got it now.

Comment: $∑_{c∈F^{×}_q}1=q-1=-1$